# How can I give an old ActiveX control new GUIDs?

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I am trying to modify an ActiveX control developed in Visual Studio 2008 to use it for a purpose for which it was not originally designed.  I will be reusing at least 90% of its code.  Therefore, I would like to begin by creating an identical control that uses different GUIDs.  I tried to follow instructions I found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21157465/Change-GUID-in-VStudio-C-OCX.html) (a very old link, written in 2004), but when I tried to build my project, I got an assertion failure in ctlreg.cpp line 113.  Then, I restored all my changed files back to their original states, and for each GUID is the .odl file, I searched for the GUID in my .cpp and .h files and changed it wherever I found it.  I also made sure to change my major version number.  I still get the assertion failure.  What else should I be doing?

Here's the code from ctlreg.cpp from the start of the method containing the assertion to the assertion itself:

```
BOOL AFXAPI AfxOleRegisterTypeLib(HINSTANCE hInstance, REFGUID tlid,
    LPCTSTR pszFileName, LPCTSTR pszHelpDir)
{   
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    CStringW strPathNameW;
    wchar_t *szPathNameW = strPathNameW.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH);
    ::GetModuleFileNameW(hInstance, szPathNameW, _MAX_PATH);
    strPathNameW.ReleaseBuffer();
    LPTYPELIB ptlib = NULL;
    // If a filename was specified, replace final component of path with it.
    if (pszFileName != NULL)
    {
        int iBackslash = strPathNameW.ReverseFind('\\');
        if (iBackslash != -1)
            strPathNameW = strPathNameW.Left(iBackslash+1);
        strPathNameW += pszFileName;
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(LoadTypeLib(strPathNameW.GetString(), &ptlib)))
    {
        ASSERT_POINTER(ptlib, ITypeLib);

        LPTLIBATTR pAttr;
        GUID tlidActual = GUID_NULL;

        if (SUCCEEDED(ptlib->GetLibAttr(&pAttr)))
        {
            ASSERT_POINTER(pAttr, TLIBATTR);
            tlidActual = pAttr->guid;
            ptlib->ReleaseTLibAttr(pAttr);
        }

        // Check that the guid of the loaded type library matches
        // the tlid parameter.
        ASSERT(IsEqualGUID(tlid, tlidActual));
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with OCX-es, a few questions come to mind:  a) I suppose you are creating the new control as a different OCX in a new project, re-using the code from the old OCX?  b) is the ,INF file set up properly?  c) did you register the OCX using `RegSvr32`?

Comment: a) I copied the entire project folder to a new folder, changed the GUIDs in the .odl file, changed the corresponding GUIDs in where they appeared in the source code files, and rebuilt.  b) I don't know.  I haven't looked at it.  Maybe that's the problem.  c) It's the process of registering the OCX with RegSvr32 that failed.

Comment: I have always used an [INF file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to describe the dependencies of the OCX (mostly third-party DLLs)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  According to that link, INF files are used to support OCX controls that are downloaded via the Internet.  I'm working locally, with the control being registered on the same machine it is being developed on.